# ng-change is not working on select in my directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-change

ng-change, ng-click not working on select only in directive
can anyone help me?

HTML

```
 <div select-list="items"></div>
```

directive:

```
myApp.directive("selectList", function(){
return function (scope, element, attr) {
    var data = scope.items;
    if(angular.isArray(data)){
        var selectElem = angular.element("<select>").attr('ng-change', 'test()');
        element.append(selectElem);
        for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++){
            var optionElem = angular.element("<option>");
            selectElem.append(optionElem.text(data[i].name));
        }
    }
}
```

});

controller:

```
var myApp=angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.controller('phoneController', function($scope) {

$scope.items = [
    {   name: 'Nokia Lumia 630'
    },
    {   name: 'Xiaomi Mi5'
    }
];

$scope.selectedItem = $scope.items[0].name;

$scope.select = function(name){
    $scope.selectedItem = name;
};
$scope.test = function(){
    alert("test");
};
```

});

im newbie here.
Angular version 1.3
 Maybe it depends on version. I cant to change version now

Comment: Can you please explain the problem a little better. At the first glance, you are adding ng-change dynamically in the directive code. It cannot be bound that way.

Comment: how can i add ng change dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $compile function if you are inserting elements with angular bindings.  Didn't test this, but it's the right direction.

```
myApp.directive("selectList", function ($compile) {
    function link(scope, element, attr) {
        var data = scope.items;
        if (angular.isArray(data)) {
            var selectElem = $compile('<select ng-change="text()"></select>');
            element.append(selectElem);
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                var optionElem = angular.element("<option>");
                selectElem.append(optionElem.text(data[i].name));
            }
        }
    }

    return {
        link: link
    };
});
```